# Retaining my decimal calculation in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, decimal, calculation

Whenever I have a decimal added to my calculation (0.052), it defaults to 0.

How can I retain the decimal calculation of my code?

For example,  int MWG = (int)(MD * **constant**); the constant is defaulted to 0 instead of 0.052.

```
public class input field: MonoBehaviour
{
    private float constant = 0.052f;

public void CasingPressure()

    {

        theTVD = inputField.GetComponent<Text>().text;
        theGas = inputFieldGas.GetComponent<Text>().text;
        theMudWeight = inputFieldMudWeight.GetComponent<Text>().text;
        theInfluxLength = inputFieldLengthofInflux.GetComponent<Text>().text;
        theFormationPressure = inputFieldFormationPressure.GetComponent<Text>().text;

        int TVD = Convert.ToInt32(theTVD);
        int KD = Convert.ToInt32(theGas);
        int MW = Convert.ToInt32(theMudWeight);
        int Influx = Convert.ToInt32(theInfluxLength);
        int FP = Convert.ToInt32(theFormationPressure);

        int C = TVD + MW;

        int HP = TVD * MW * (int)(constant);
        int SDIPP = FP - HP ;
        int MD = MW - KD;
        int MWG = (int)(MD * constant);
        int LMWG = MWG * Influx;
        int SICPP = LMWG + SDIPP;
        textDisplayCP.GetComponent<Text>().text = " " + SICPP + " psi";

    }
```

Comment: It's not that the value of `constant` defaults to zero. It's that you're casting to `int`. If you want the decimals to remain, you have to make the types compatible by casting towards the type that has decimals. Cast the `int`s to `float`, rather than the other way around.

Comment: ints do not support "decimals" or floating point values, if you want to keep your decimal, don't use an int.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give it a try.

Comment: The type storing the result will also need to be one that supports decimals. In this case, `float`. --- `float MWG = (float)MD * constant;`

Comment: Casting a floating point number to an integer type rounds towards zero. In this case, casting `constant` as an `int` rounds it to `0`.

Comment: @AresCaelum Why would rounding 5.75 towards zero give you 6?

Comment: Maybe you should reread my comment, because you don't seem to be seeing the "towards zero" part of it.

Comment: So far, adding the float fixed my problem since int doesn't allow decimal.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @AresCaelum Rounding towards zero gives you the same result as truncation, so all that you're doing is arguing semantics. Yes, the computer just discards the fractional component when casting to an integer type.

Comment: It took me a while to sloved that problem since I'm not a programmer.  You save me an hour of downtime.

Comment: BTW, how do I display commas to a large number?

Comment: @coder `myVariableName.ToString("N2")` the number being the amount of decimal points you want to display. If you want to show only a whole number, use `N0`

Comment: Thanks Ron for the commas suggestion.